# Write to device failed (no link / unknown error / too many links)

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, fastboot

I am trying to flash TWRP to my ZTE Axon 7, but until now I just keep getting errors every time I try to flash something.

```
D:\ZTE Axon 7>fastboot devices
a773911d        fastboot

D:\ZTE Axon 7>fastboot flash recovery "D:\ZTE Axon 7\twrp-3.5.2_9-0-ailsa_ii.img"
Sending 'recovery' (16104 KB)                      FAILED (Write to device failed (Unknown error))
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

When I look at any guides/videos online, it just works, but not for me. The device is already wiped and the bootloader is unlocked. I also tried some commands like `clear cache` and `reboot bootloader`, but they produce the same kind of error. I am in fastboot mode, I also get some unknown error in MiFlash.

[image]

So basically I haven't really been able to flash anything. Already tried different ports and cables, don't have any other cables lying around.

Trying to use `fastboot boot` (different USB ports):

```
C:\adb-platform-tools>fastboot boot twrp-3.5.2_9-0-ailsa_ii.img
Sending 'boot.img' (16104 KB)                      FAILED (Status read failed (Too many links))
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\adb-platform-tools>fastboot boot twrp-3.5.2_9-0-ailsa_ii.img
Sending 'boot.img' (16104 KB)                      FAILED (Write to device failed in SendBuffer() (Too many links))
fastboot: error: Command failed

C:\adb-platform-tools>fastboot boot twrp-3.5.2_9-0-ailsa_ii.img
Sending 'boot.img' (16104 KB)                      FAILED (Status read failed (Too many links))
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Really running out of ideas on this one, I've already tried numerous things and keep getting a variation of these "Write to device failed" errors all the time.

PC does have a Ryzen 5800x, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: "Too many links" does not mean that your Android had too many sausages for breakfast. This stupidity has persisted for too long. In Linux EMLINK (Too many Links) is 31. In Windows 0x0000001f is "A device attached to the system is not functioning". In Fastboot for Windows they let a Windows error get translated as a Linux error. In short, the Android was not responding over USB. Why is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the solution is pretty weird.

I was reading [MrNoob - How to fix data transfer failure (Too many links) error in Fastboot?](https://mrnoob.net/data-transfer-failure-too-many-links-fix/) which mentions something about Windows 10 drivers being problematic, so it is suggested to use a USB 2.0 adapter or something similar. So I have one of those and tried a command, and it worked. Next, I tried flashing

```
fastboot flash boot twrp.img
```

But it still didn't work and got the "Couldn’t parse partition size ‘0x’". But I thought to myself how can this be, one command works and the next just fails like that all of a sudden.

Then I read through [DroidWin - How To Fix Fastboot: Error: Couldn’t Parse Partition Size ‘0x’](https://www.droidwin.com/fix-fastboot-error-couldnt-parse-partition-size-0x/). I guess you can skip the root requirements for now and look at the flash command used:

```
fastboot flash:raw boot twrp.img
```

However, this still didn't work and I have tried it before, do you know why? In my case, it's really f-ing weird.

One thing I must mention before this is that I also installed the "QDLoader HS-USB Driver_64bit" drivers, on Windows 10. This will now display some "Test Mode" text on the lower right because these drivers are not signed by Microsoft.

1. Connect the phone to USB 2.0 adapter with a proper cable
2. Make sure the device shows up in fastboot devices
3. The weird thing is, DO NOT use any peripherals like a wireless mouse on the same USB adapter the phone is connected to. It probably interferes with it somehow.
4. Now run the command and it should work (you can use `fastboot reboot bootloader` just to make sure it's OK and commands work)

Might have to repeat these steps if the commands stop working again.

Answer (score 1):

I've been going through every step you're all talking about. Most of the articles are fairly accurate, but they're outdated.

It's a weird procedure and you have to have the right tools installed (drivers, software, etc.). But, I've found that the key is in the order that you do these steps for fastboot to connect (recognize the device).

It's still a trial-and-error but so far, I've deduced:
Once you have everything set up correctly, unplug the device from USB, enter flash mode, plug in the device, run `fastboot devices`, and verify it's detected (make sure it's the only thing that is connected). If it's not detected, the fastboot command will fail. If it is connected, run your fastboot command and cross your fingers!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely port’s problem, use usb2.0 port instead will solve it all.